# C++ trying to determine the highest and lowest number and getting a long decimal number

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the highest and lowest number you input out of 10 numbers. Determining the highest number works just fine, but when I try to apply the same method to getting the lowest number I keep getting this number, 6.00758e-039.

My header for the class:

```
 #ifndef GRADE_H
#define GRADE_H

using namespace std;

class Grade
{
    public:
        Grade();
        void getGrades();
        float detHighest();
        float detLowest();
    protected:
    private:
        float grades[10];
        int x;
        float z, y;
        float *highest, *lowest;
};

#endif // GRADE_H
```

This is the class where I get the numbers and determine which numbers are higher and lower than each other.

```
Grade::Grade()
{
    highest = &y;
    lowest = &z;
}

void Grade::getGrades(){
    cout << "Enter 10 grades to be stored." << endl;
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        cout << (x + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> grades[x];
    }
}

float Grade::detHighest(){
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        if(grades[x] > y)
            *highest = grades[x];
    }
    return y;
}

float Grade::detLowest(){
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        if(grades[x] < z)
            *lowest = grades[x];
    }
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Even for the highest that works it's out of pure luck. You don't initialize `y` and `z` anywhere.

Comment: btw, except `grades`, other members should be local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class member "y" appears to be uninitialized. Unless there's additional code that you did not show, this is undefined behavior. The first time you enter the loop that searches for the highest or the lowest value, you will end up comparing an uninitialized class member, whose value will be random binary garbage.

Comment: Is it bad practice to initialize it with a really large and small number to make it so the biggest and lowest number will be the one they entered?

Comment: @JordanK: That's a common approach.  An even better approach is to initialize to the first item, that way you don't have to worry that some item actually it outside the values you picked.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pointer to an uninitialized variable is considered bad practice. In the instructor you're setting the value of the two pointers to the address of y and z but they're not initialized so they both contain garbage. The simplest way to solve the problem is to have two floats that contain the highest and lowest value later but initialize them with -1 first. To determine the highest value set the highest float variable to the value of the first grade then compare it to each grade then replace it if it's greater. you can add an if statement to test if the function returns -1 then there's an error.